# Setter ignored when property is assigned to variable (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, setter

I'm creating a Verdict class which will evaluate to true until it is set false after which it always evaluates false even if you set it to true. The only way I could think of to do that would be to have a property and a setter.

It works, but for simplicity rather than having:

```
v = Verdict()
v.verdict = ...
v.verdict = ...
v.verdict = ...
```

I thought I could do:

```
v = Verdict().verdict
v = ...
v = ...
v = ...
```

But it seems that v in the second case is the attribute directly, and is ignoring the setter.

```
class Verdict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__verdict = True

    @property
    def verdict(self):
        return self.__verdict

    @verdict.setter
    def verdict(self, value):
        if self.__verdict is True:
            self.__verdict = value

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.__verdict

class A():
    v = Verdict().verdict
    y = Verdict()

    def foo(cls):
        cls.y = False
        cls.y = True # Uses setter and stays false
        cls.v = False
        cls.v = True # should use setter and stay false but doesn't
```

Is there a way to fix this, or a better method to achieve the Verdict?

Comment: Would you expect `y` to change if you did `x = y; x = 3`?

Comment: Are you coming to Python from C++? If so, explaining why things are different is a bit more involved (unless you can just forget what you learned from C++ and think of this like a new programmer).

Comment: Anyway,. `v = <something>` just says "make `v` a name for the value you get by evaluating `<something>`. This is done by asking the appropriate (local or global) namespace to store `<something>` under the name `v`. But `v.verdict = <something>` means "make `v.verdict` a name for the value you get by evaluating `<something>`", which can only be done by asking `v` to do it, which is done by calling `v.__setattr__('verdict', <the value>)`.

Comment: @user2357112. IDK If x is a pointer and y is an address, then yes. Stuffs weird for a C++ programmer. I can assign a Python variable to a function, so is x then a variable or a function pointer? I was expecting that if I assigned x to a parameter then it would be a pointer to the parameter, and not the underlying attribute. But it seems not. I don't think I understand what a parameter actually is, I think I need to read about decorators.

Comment: @abarnet My logic was:
    `Verdict().verdict = True`    <-calls the setter for verdict. So
    `v = Verdict().verdict`
    `v = True`      <- v evaluates to Verdict().verdict and calls the setter for verdict.
But instead it seems
   `v = True`      <- v evaluates to Verdict().verdict and sets the attribute verdict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid using the `v.verdict = ...` syntax.

This is because properties require attribute access in order to work. Properties are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and the descriptor protocol only takes effect on attribute access.

If you store a property (or, more generally, a descriptor) in a variable, you've effectively robbed it of its functionality. Accessing a variable is just a name lookup, and assigning to a variable is just binding a value to a name. It's not possible to make an assignment like `v = ...` trigger your setter.